# Refused to execute javascript because MIME type is empty, nodeJS + express + engintron + nginx

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx

I currently have an issue that's causing me to pull my hair out.

*So here's what you need to know*

My app is running node.js (16.13.1), with express and nginx via engintron as the app is hosted with cPanel.

Here's my app.mjs

```
//The dependencies the app needs
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import express from 'express'; //Imports the express package that we installed with npm install express

import request from 'request'; //Imports the express package that we installed with npm install request

import bodyParser from 'body-parser'; //Imports the express package that we installed with npm install bodyParser

import path from 'path'; //Imports the express package that we installed with npm install path

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const expressapp = express(); //Creates the application with express

const moduleURL = new URL(import.meta.url);

const __dirname = path.dirname(moduleURL.pathname);

//Middleware

expressapp.use(express.json()); //Tells express to use JSON as it's input

expressapp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); //Encodes the URL in the body of the app's request so that they remain secure.

expressapp.use(express.static(__dirname, {index: 'index.html'})); //Tells the app to use the current path, with the index being index.html

console.log("The directory used is", (path.join(__dirname, '/assets')));

expressapp.post('/subscribe', (req, res) => { //Makes a post request to the subscribe route where req is the request and res is the response
    const { email, js } = req.body; //Create a constant that makes up of the request's body

    const mcData = { REDACTED } //This app involves sending a request to the MailChimp API, so this JSON object contains some of my authorization keys :)

    const mcDataPost = JSON.stringify(mcData); //Turns the JSON object into a string

    const options = { REDACTED } //Some more personal data here

    if (email) { REDACTED } //The code where the email that gets sent to the API, this has been confirmed to be working as intended. 
});


expressapp.listen(5000, console.log('Server started on port 5000!')); //Console log that confirms the start of the server

export default expressapp;
```

Followed by my declaration in index.html.

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="../app.mjs"></script>
```

Also side note, I have the application/javascript inside the etc/nginx/mime.types file as my javascript MIME type.

Speaking of nginx, here's my default.conf if that matters at all (i'm not too sure)

```
server {
    #listen 80 default_server;
    listen 80;
    
    server_name domain name, followed by IP address; 

    # deny all; # DO NOT REMOVE OR CHANGE THIS LINE - Used when Engintron is disabled to block Nginx from becoming an open proxy

    # Set the port for HTTP proxying
    set $PROXY_TO_PORT 8080;

    include common_http.conf;
}
```

common_http.conf

```
location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
}
```

nginx.conf

```
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
```

When my app launches, it refuses to execute the app.mjs script because it's MIME type is (''). I'm wondering what exactly is causing the MIME type not to be passed so that my site can run properly. I would appreciate it if someone could give me some assistance on what's going on here.

Proof of error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzOM3.jpg

Answer (score -1):

You can fix it by explicitly adding a module javascript type to the nginx/etc/mime.types file like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCnAI.jpg

Use some sort of text editor (such as nano) to do so, just figured that out lol.

Comment: Please consider modifying to use `application/javascript` instead of `application/modulejs`. [See mime for .mjs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types).

Comment: @AnthumChris alright, thank you!