Configuring Flutter Web app under subpath with Nginx in development/production mode
I am developing a web app in Flutter. The app will be part of a bigger project: an API is already done, and another app needs to be created. I'd like to put everything under the same domain name. Subdomains (in the context of cookies for authentication) led to a lot of CORS issues and therefore I've decided to put the multiple apps under subpaths under the the same domain:

http://localhost:8081/api calls the api
http://localhost:8081/app1 should request the first app
http://localhost:8081/app2 should request the second app

Both in production and in development I use Nginx as a server. And I just cannot get it to work. Here's what I have at the moment:
Nginx (after my own failures I got the following from ChatGPT)
server {
        listen       8081;
        server_name  localhost;

        access_log /opt/homebrew/var/log/nginx/access.log;

        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/api;
        }

        location /app1 {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3666;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

                # Ensure the /app1 subpath works correctly with the Flutter app
                sub_filter 'href="/' 'href="/app1/';
                sub_filter 'src="/' 'src="/app1/';
                sub_filter 'content="/' 'content="/app1/';
                sub_filter_once off;
        }

        # app2 is a problem for later
}

In the Flutter app, /web/index.html, I have the standard:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    ...

I have experimented with the href parameter (setting it to "/app1/") to no avail.
Going to main.dart, I have configured GoRouter like this:
Future<void> main() async {
  usePathUrlStrategy();
  ....
}

// function that returns the GoRouter configuration
// ------------------------------------------------
GoRouter getRouter(WidgetRef ref) {
  ....
  //
  return  GoRouter(
    initialLocation: '/agenda',
    routes: [
      ShellRoute(
        builder: (context, state, child) {
          return TvsScaffold(
            child: child
          );
        },
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            name: 'app1',
            path: '/', // <<=========== !!!!
            builder: (context, state) => const Dashboard(),
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                name: 'home',
                path: 'dashboard',
                builder: (context, state) => const Dashboard(),
              ),

I thought that in GoRouter I had to set path to '/app1 but this doesn't work (see line with the arrow).
When I call localhost:8081/app1/whatever I see in the browser's console: Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8081/app1/flutter_bootstrap.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled., and Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error. which are not very helpful.
I want to connect the dots here: how can I put several Flutter web-apps under the same domain. I don't care if it has to be under subdomains or subpaths. As written I got into CORS troubles with subdomains, hence my attempt to use subpaths.

The actual error you are getting about MIME types does not seem to be about CORS at all. If you serve JavaScript, then yes, it needs to be the right type. It looks like you have an Nginx listener at the front, and that proxies to a Flutter listener at the back. I assume either of them could be used to force the right header in the response for files matching *.js.

Your strategy of putting all sub-applications behind a proxy server is sound; even if CORS can be made to work, using non-standard ports can get your application into a pickle with users' VPNs, business internet proxies, and mobile internet connections. Stick to 443 incoming (i.e. only one port) if you can.

How are you compiling app1? Rather than modifying the html/index.html, use the command flutter build web --base-href=/app1/

Thanks for taking the time to respond @halfer. I mentioned the CORS thing because I got into a lot of trouble at some point using subdomains. That's why I went for subpaths. At this time, I don't have any CORS problems. I believe it's all about GoRouter and index.html. I think I am missing something, but after days I am still knowhere and can't find appropriate examples or clues.

Thanks @RichardHeap: I have done that. But as I wrote to -halfer- I am forgetting about the production environment. I am just running Flutter on port 3666 locally and also use Nginx locally to mimic what I would like to have on the production server. If any of you would have a starting point to trace I would very much appreciate it. Completely thrashing in the dark here, don't know where to start after  many many attempts.

Have you added an explicit Content-Type response header for *.js files in either of your listener configs? I believe it should be application/javascript. If you don't know which config to put it in, I would generally put it in the Nginx.

Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70424890. Please do try it, and report back here.

I have tried the above, but no joy. The problem is now shifting towards something else and I still have no clue why everything is getting so complicated. Maybe you have an idea. Things have changed when I added a trailing slash in the NginX config: proxy_pass http://localhost:3666/; (suggested by ChatGPT). So now the bootstrap / MIME type problem is "solved", leaving me with another hurdle: client.js:9617 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/$dwdsSseHandler' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. It's a gift that keeps on giving. Any idea?

It sounds like you are trying to solve too many problems at once. Nevertheless, I think you are on the right path; the problem in this question is solved, and you can add an answer. I recommend you do that, and then ask a new question. I would recommend that the new question is more focussed i.e. try to not mention CORS, since you have solved that. I would also suggest not introducing wider doubts about your architecture; currently you have chosen a direction and, for what it is worth, it sounds fine to me.

In the new question it may be worth noting what you do have working: does /api work but /app1 does not? Is the first one HTTP and the second one a WebSocket etc.?
